# How can I add a # before my color in jpicker

Tags: jquery, colors, format

My software is working great with jquery jpicker.  I am getting a color such as FF0000, but I would like to add the "#" while entering the information to have it #FF0000.  I'm assuming you do it during a callback, but I couldn't figure that out.

Also, I'd like to be able to enter "red" or "blue", but it seems that there is a keypress submit that is not allowing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you post some code so people can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of [this web page](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/), you can see the example.

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

Comment: I can see the generic example of the Color Picker,  however the result is the 6 digit color without the '#' in front... I want the '#' to appear in the text input box when you select the color.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit jpicker-1.1.6.js for this:

Row ~455 (For change it inside INPUT - live editing) ...

```
bindedHex.val(bindedHex.val().replace(/[^a-fA-F0-9]/g, '').toLowerCase().substring(0, 6));
```

to

```
bindedHex.val(bindedHex.val().replace(/[^#a-fA-F0-9]/g, '').toLowerCase().substring(0, 7));
```

Row ~482 (For change it inside INPUT - after editing) ...

```
bindedHex && bindedHex.val(color.val('hex'));
```

to

```
bindedHex && bindedHex.val('#'+color.val('hex'));
```

Row ~525 (For change it in color panel) ...

```
if (bindedHex && context != bindedHex.get(0) && context != hex.get(0)) bindedHex.val(all != null ? all.hex : '');
```

to

```
if (bindedHex && context != bindedHex.get(0) && context != hex.get(0)) bindedHex.val(all != null ? '#'+all.hex : '');
```